# AngularJS ng-repeat freezes browser while HighCharts render

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, rendering, angularjs-ng-repeat

Inside ng-repeat, I have a directive that fetches data using $http, then on success, initializes and renders Highcharts.

html :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <mychart datasource="item.id"></mychart>
</div>
```

js :

```
.directive('mychart', function($http){
    template: '<div>Loading chart...</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        datasource : '='
    },
    link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $http(...).success( function (data) {

            var chartOptions = {
                chart : {
                    type: 'column',
                    renderTo: element[0]
                },
                xAxis : {
                    categories : data
                }
                ...
            };

            new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);  <!-- freezes browser?? -->

         });
    };
});
```

$http is asynchronous so there is no blocking there.  But I believe calling Highcharts creates browser freeze.
Is there a way to achieve non-blocking rendering?  Would implementing $q be an option here?  $evalAsync??
I think calling "new" inside link runs in global scope.  Would this be a problem?  Just fuzzy with what I need to do.  Thanks for any advises.

Comment: is it slowing down processing? try limiting the list to a handful of items, like 2-3 and see how long it takes to render

Comment: On desktop, hardly noticeable.  But of course, on mobile devices, freeze is significant.  Yes, limiting the data helps but still freeze flickers happen on iPad even with 20 items.

Comment: ok, so what you might want to do is process each chart one at a time. You can set up an array to house the promises and draw the chart, and then make the next $http service call, then draw again, and so on, iterating through your array of service calls. Basically, you need to limit the processing being done to one chart at a time (on mobile)

Comment: The processing is slow because you will do 20 http calls all at once inside the ng-repeat and then try to draw all the charts as soon as data comes back.

Comment: $http would be fine inside ng-repeat because async calls, right?  32.214 ms Loading
1.48 s Scripting
672.482 ms Rendering
66.515 ms Painting  (Rendering is pretty much all highcharts.js)

Comment: Kinda, but not really... it needs to be structured so as to queue up the requests. lets say you have a list of 20 items, then you will make 20 $http calls. Assuming the response time is fast, you will get ALL the data back fairly fast and then need to process it. What I'm suggesting is that you get data for only one item at a time, process it, draw the chart (which is not async) and then make the next call.

Comment: I suggest you create a service, the service handles $http calls for your directive. The service has an array of calls which it will store (you can create a function wrapper for this). Add all the requests to the array when the call is made and return a promise, which will be resolved when the call is made. Then process the array as long as length is > 0, resolve promises as you go. Once a promise is resolved and your directive receives a success response, start drawing, then tell the service to process the next request.

Comment: Really appreciate your help but I cant seem to get my head around it.  When do I build the http request array?  Inside directive??

Comment: Another option is to go with web workers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a repeating directive and it slows your page load down because on a lower powered device it tries to do lots and lots of computation.

It is my opinion that you would see a performance improvement if you queued up your function calls and fulfilled them sequentially.

Higher level idea:

[image: design]

Code, should work for you:

```
// this service stores a request queue, allows adding requests to the queue and runs the function calls recursively. (This really queues up any functions you want to run sequentially, but relies on promises)

angular.module(Global.Application.name).service('queuedService', ['$q', '$http',
    function($q, $http)  {

        var arrayOfCalls = [];

        // this is what you add to the queue, what this does is wrap a function and 
        var functionWrapper = function(fn, context, params, onSuccess, onFailure){
            return function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var self = this;
                var a = fn.apply(context, params);
                a.then(function(response){
                     onSuccess.apply(self, [response]);
                     deferred.resolve(response);
                }, function(reason){
                    onFailure.apply(self, [reason]);
                    deferred .reject(reason);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            };
        };

        function runArrayOfCalls(){
            alreadyRunning = true;
            if(arrayOfCalls.length > 0){
                    (arrayOfCalls.shift())().then(function(response){
                        console.log('succeeded - calls remaining', arrayOfCalls.length);
                        runArrayOfCalls();
                    }, function(){
                         console.log('failed - call remaining:', arrayOfCalls.length);
                        runArrayOfCalls();
                    });
            } else {
                alreadyRunning = false;
            }
        }

        // parametersObject could be an array or object passed, prefer object
        var addRequest= function(parametersObject, context, onSuccess, onFailure){
            // likely way to do this
            var config = {
                method: parametersObject.method, //"GET", "POST", etc 
                url: parametersObject.url, //"http://www.something.com", 
                headers: parametersObject.headers, //{"content-type": "application/json"}
            }
            if(parametersObject.data){
                if(config.method.toUpperCase() === "GET")
                    config.params = parametersObject.data; // get request
                else if(config.method.toUpperCase() === "POST")
                    config.data = parametersObject.data; // post request
            }

            var delayed = functionWrapper($http, context, parametersObject, onSuccess, onFailure);
            arrayOfCalls.push(delayed);

            runArrayOfCalls(); // auto run this array of calls
        };

        return {
            addRequestToQueue: function(parametersObject, context, onSuccess, onFailure){
                addRequest(parametersObject, context, onSuccess, onFailure);
            }, 
            fulfillNextRequest: function(){
                if(!alreadyRunning)
                    runArrayOfCalls();
            }
        };


    }
]);
```

Assuming your directive is something like this, notice this is not a complete directive, just the part that does the linking

```
angular.module(Global.Application.name).directive('myDirective', ['queuedService',
    function(queuedService)  {

        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                 var self = this; // this will be used for context of function wrapper
                 // take data in directive and add request
                 var parameters = {
                     url: 'something',
                     method: 'GET',
                     data: {
                         param1: "stuff"
                     }
                 }
                 var onSuccess = function(response){
                     console.log('response', response);
                     // draw chart here
                 };
                 var onFailure= function(reason){
                     console.log('failure');
                 };

                 queuedService.addRequestToQueue(parametersObject, self, onSuccess, onFailure);

            }
        }

    }
]);
```

This is not a complete solution but should take you pretty far.